# LINQ to SQL Search Query results to listbox, help transferring selecteditems to a new listbox

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq, listbox, selecteditem

Hello and thank you for your help ahead of time!

I am doing a project with vb.net that involves searching a database table named 'Movies'. I have a related table 'Directors', and the goal of the project is to enable users to search and select movies to purchase.

I have figured out how to query the database using LINQ to SQL, and the results populate in my ListBox properly, but when I go to add the user's SELECTED ITEMS to a new listbox, or even try to display them in a messagebox, the result is not correct.

To be clear, the I am using LINQ to SQL because it allows me to manipulate related tables a lot easier and is much easier for querying than using plain SQL in vb.net.

Below is an example of my code

```
    Dim db As DataClasses1DataContext = New DataClasses1DataContext

    Dim searchstring As String = txtSearchbyText.Text
    Dim data As System.Linq.IQueryable(Of Project_2010Version.Movies)



    data = From m In db.Movies _
           Where m.MovTitle = searchstring _
           Select m

    ListBox1.DataSource = data.ToList
    ListBox1.DisplayMember = "MovTitle"
    ListBox1.ValueMember = "MovTitle"
```

What I want to do from here is allow users to select items from the listbox and then populate those items on a new "Order Form"

The problem I am running into is that the selected items being transferred do not display the correct values when trying to access them.

If I run the following code

```
Dim oitem As Object = Nothing

    For Each oitem In ListBox1.SelectedItems
        MsgBox(oitem.ToString())
    Next
```

My problem is the only thing I get in return is "Project2010Verion.Movies" instead of the movie's title.

How can I get the correct title so it can be displayed on a new form?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem with the iterator loop (`For Each`) is that you are calling `ToString` on an object, which, of course, will return the fully qualified name of the object in the list.

Look up what you have in the `Movies` class, pretty sure you want to structure it as:

```
For Each oitem In ListBox1.SelectedItems
        MsgBox(oitem.MovTitle)
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try something like this..

For Each oitem In ListBox1.SelectedItems
        MsgBox(Listbox1.GetItemText(oitem))
    Next